# CouchDB not updating view for upcoming and past events

Tags: date, view, couchdb

I have the following view on couchdb that will only return docs with a date greater than the current date like:

```
function (doc) {

    var eventDay = new Date(new Date(doc.start).toDateString()),
        currentDay = new Date(new Date().toDateString());

    if (eventDay > currentDay) {
       emit();
    }
}
```

So in this case the view will always show future(upcoming) events only. I also have the same inverted view to show only past events. But the problem is that apparently the view is not being updated on the next day. So I have to update the view manually by adding few line breaks and so I guess this causes a ‘refresh’.

Any ideas on how I could make this work?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget that the map code per entry is executed on document creation/change, thus you will not have consistent values for what you regard as "currentDay".

Instead, you must build a view that allows you to add this information during the query. Here is an example:

```
funciton(doc){

    //Extract from date object.
    var year = ..;
    var month = ..;
    var day = ..;
    //..

    emit([year,month,day], null);
}
```

This will create an complex index, ordered by (year,month,day). You can now query for partial ranges, for instance all dates in the future, by using startkey/endkey. Please see the View API for details: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Comment: thanks a lot for this PartlyCloudy. So you meant that the views will not be _refreshed_ until a document is created or updated? hence the need of querying with start and end keys since those values would be different each day and then output consistent results?

Comment: Think of the view index as a sorted list that will be updated incrementally on changes - new documents will be inserted, changed documents re-inserted. Your "current day" attribute is something that you need during your query, not when building the view. In a nutshell, you'll have a long sorted list of documents (by date) and query partial ranges using startkeys and endkeys.

Comment: +1. Right, views are a way of building a completely *static* index of the original data. The index can be incrementally updated as documents change but for the most part it sits quite still. When you query the view, CouchDB always scans the index. That's fast and predictable. The only control you have is the `startkey` and `endkey` per query.

Comment: @b_erb function is/was misspelled as funciton in your answer.